# Grafana with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana

I am trying to create a graph in Grafana, with datasource from ElasticSearch. I get error stating that there is no datapoints. Moreover in the Metrics field if I select any value (count, avg, max....) I get the index fields (eg cpu.usage.total) in the dropdown menu and not the @value or @number

Grafana Dashboard_1  --

[image]

Grafana Dashboard_2  --

[image]

Comment: Are `@number` and `@value` part of the schema?

Answer (score 0):

Just found that I had not provided the correct parameter while creating the  data source and hence was not able to generate the charts. I am now able to generate the graphs. But it seems that the container names are not getting displayed properly where there is a special character "-" in the container name.

Comment: What parameter were you missing?